# Hibernate JPA, one to one relationship with a composite key and a constant value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm attempting to implement a limited type of object level ACL and its lead me to a place where I'm attempting to create a `@OneToOne` relationship using a composite key with a constant and dynamic value.

I have an Entity with a database id and a constant value defined in the class.

```
public class Entity{

    private static final int objectType = 1;

    @Id
    Integer id;
}
```

I have an `access_levels` table with a composite key of `objectId` and `objectType`.

```
public class AccessLevel {

@EmbeddedId
private AccessLevelKey accessLevelKey;

     @Embeddable
     class AccessLevelKey implements Serializable{

           private Integer objectType;
           private Integer objectId;
           ....
      }
}
```

Schema of `access_levels`

```
CREATE TABLE access_levels(
    object_type INTEGER NOT NULL,
    object_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ....
    CONSTRAINT access_levels_type_id PRIMARY KEY (object_type, object_id)
);
```

I'm attempting to come up with a one to one relationship that `Entity` can use to fetch and update its associated `AccessLevel`

After taking a look a the docs on [Non-Standard Joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs40/full/html/ref_guide_mapping_notes_nonstdjoins.html) it seems like I need something like this,

Inside of Entity:

```
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "object_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "access_levels.object_type", referencedColumnName = "1"),
     })
     private AccessLevel accessLevel;
```

However this throws a hibernate `MappingException` at app launch

`Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: 1 in access_levels`

Thanks!

Comment: Any update on this? Did you find the solution?

Comment: @DianaR, nope sorry. Ended up going with a different approach

Comment: same for me, tried a few things and none of them worked :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a constant in Join Columns, just use a formula and put your constant in the value attribute. But remember to add double and single quotes around "'{your constant value}'" to prevent any errors.

Example:

```sql
@OneToOne
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
   @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="'1'", referencedColumnName="object_type")),
   @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn("id", referencedColumnName ="object_id"))
})
private AccessLevel accessLevel;
```